# ¿como pudo obtener Logs en la plataforma Graylog desde una Asp.Net core web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, log

tengo estos dos metodos:

```
builder.Host.ConfigureSerilog();
builder.Services.AddLogging(logger => logger.AddSerilog());
```

como puedo aplicarlos al momento de realizar el **build**, ya que en mi ejemplo lo aplica de esta manera:

```
    using Serilog;
    using testGraylog;
    
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
    
    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    builder.Host.ConfigureSerilog();
    builder.Services.AddLogging(logger => logger.AddSerilog());
    
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    
    app.UseRouting();
    
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    
    app.Run();
```

y yo quisiera aplicarlo aqui, pero mi api utiliza las clases setup y program

```
      CC.Utils.Consul.ConsulWebHostBuilder.CreateWebHostBuilder(configuration, CC.Utils.Consul.Application.Type.Api, assembly, args).UseStartup<Startup>().ConfigureServices((services) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($".... CreateWebHostBuilder");
                var healthPort = CC.Utils.Consul.Config.Get(CC.Utils.Consul.Config.CONSUL_CONFIG_SERVICE_HEALT_PORT, CC.Utils.Consul.Root.Configuration);
                Console.WriteLine($".... CONSUL_CONFIG_SERVICE_HEALT_PORT : {healthPort}");
                var address = CC.Utils.Consul.Config.Get(CC.Utils.Consul.Config.CONSUL_CONFIG_HOST, CC.Utils.Consul.Root.Configuration);
                Console.WriteLine($".... CONSUL_CONFIG_HOST : {address}");
    
    
                CC.Utils.Config.Globals.Builder ??= (new());
                CC.Utils.Config.Globals.Builder.ReloadOnChange = true;
                CC.Utils.Config.Globals.Builder.Configuration ??= CC.Utils.Consul.Root.Configuration;
    
                CC.Utils.LoggerELK.Configure.ConfigureLogging(CC.Utils.Consul.Root.Configuration, assembly);
    
            }).UseSerilog().Build().Run();
```

como este metodo tiene configurado el UseSerilog, pero al descargar los paqutes de graylog me sale que el metodo esta deprecado ya que apartir de .net 6.0 en vez de usar **IWebHostBuilder** usa **IHostBuilde**